# Chef 12 Deprecated Warning for Exit Values

Tags: chef-infra

Chef 12 says this is deprecated exit value code, which will not be accepted by Chef 13:

Chef::Application.fatal!("Could not find any Cores servers. Are the nodes tagged?")

https://docs.chef.io/deprecations_exit_code.html  and https://github.com/chef/chef-rfc/blob/master/rfc062-exit-status.md  try to define how to write exit codes according to Chef 13 rules, but unfortunately for me 
they are written in Martian.

Can anyone tell me how to rewrite the line:

Chef::Application.fatal!("Could not find any Cores servers. Are the nodes tagged?")

... so that it returns a non-deprecated exit code, and also returns the string containing the error message?

Comment: Are you sure that's the exact code that is failing? Because that shouldn't be happening.

Comment: Code isn't failing. It compiles - with a warning message about deprecated code for exit values - when compiled with Chef 12.  Chef 13 will treat the above code as a compile error.

Comment: Yes but are you sure the line of code is exactly what you showed?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a replacement for Chef::Application.fatal! that CHEF 13 will not treat as a compile error?